# dialog interrupted in middle of a prompt only resumes from beginning of the prompt step

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to design a dinner ordering bot. There is a 'orderDinner' dialog which has only two functions --> prompt text and process the response. In context of 'orderDinner' dialog, beginDialogAction is done for trigger 'alcohol'. It invokes a new dialog 'checkAge'. What I want is after checkAge is done and age is validated the 'orderDinner' dialog should be resume from step 2 but it always starts from step 1. Below is the code:

```
bot.dialog('orderDinner', [
function (session, args){
    let promptmessage;
    if (args && args.resumed == true) {
        promptmessage = 'What else would you like to add?';
    } else {
        promptmessage = 'What would you like to order today?';
    }
    promptmessage += '(_type done when no more items to add_)';
    builder.Prompts.text(session, promptmessage);
},
function (session, results, args) {
    session.send(`${results.response} added to dinner cart!`);
    session.replaceDialog('orderDinner', {
        resumed : true
    });
}
]).beginDialogAction('checkAge', 'checkAge', {
    matches: /^alcohol$/i
}).beginDialogAction('doneOrderDinner', 'doneOrderDinner', {
    matches: /^done$/i
})

bot.dialog('doneOrderDinner',[
    (session) => {
        session.send("Food will be on your way");
        session.replaceDialog('mainBotMenu');
    }
])

bot.dialog('checkAge', [
    (session, result) => {
        builder.Prompts.number(session, 'Please enter your age');
    },
    (session, result) => {
        let canGetAlcohol = false;
        if(result.response > 18) {
            session.send('You can get alcohol');
            canGetAlcohol = true;
        } else {
            session.send('Too young for alcohol');
        }
        const dialogResult = { resumed : true, canGetAlcohol : canGetAlcohol }
        session.endDialogWithResult(dialogResult)
    }
]);
```

Is there any way to achieve this without breaking the flow? Now, the message:
'alcohol added to cart' is never printed

Answer (score 0):

You've passed wrong parameters in functions in your `orderDinner` dialog, the function should be a dialog or array of dialogs which implements `IDialogWaterfallStep` interface, and `IDialogWaterfallStep` is like this:

```
export interface IDialogWaterfallStep {
    /**
     * @param session Session object for the current conversation.
     * @param result
     * * __result:__ _{any}_ - For the first step of the waterfall this will be `null` or the value of any arguments passed to the handler.
     * * __result:__ _{IDialogResult}_ - For subsequent waterfall steps this will be the result of the prompt or dialog called in the previous step.
     * @param skip Function used to manually skip to the next step of the waterfall.
     * @param skip.results (Optional) results to pass to the next waterfall step. This lets you more accurately mimic the results returned from a prompt or dialog.
     */
    (session: Session, result?: any | IDialogResult<any>, skip?: (results?: IDialogResult<any>) => void): any;
}
```

So in your code the parameter `resumed` should be in the variable `results`. Now you can modify your code for example like this:

```
function (session, args){
    let promptmessage;
    if (args && args.resumed) {
        promptmessage = 'What else would you like to add?';
    } else {
        promptmessage = 'What would you like to order today?';
    }
    promptmessage += '(_type done when no more items to add_)';
    builder.Prompts.text(session, promptmessage);
},
function (session, results) {
    session.send(`${results.response} added to dinner cart!`);
    session.replaceDialog('orderDinner', {
        resumed : true
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But still I am not able to achieve what is intended.  "Alcohol added to cart" is not printed, i.e., after the 'checkAge' dialog it starts the order dinner from the first step.

Comment: @Sushovan, are you sure you didn't change any other code? I used your code and just modified the parameters as I said in my answer, the "Alcohol added to cart" shows well on my side.

Comment: Yes it the exact same code. It is interesting. So just to confirm you go through the checkAge dialog and then "Alcohol added to cart" message is received. Is it possible to paste the code here. I will run the exact same and see if I have messed up some setting. Thanks!!

Comment: @Sushovan, oh sorry, I understand your issue now. The `checkAge` dialog will end with `resumed : true, canGetAlcohol : canGetAlcohol`, it will directly go back to the waterfall step 1, the `session.send(`${results.response} added to dinner cart!`);` is in the step 2. If you want to show "Alcohol added to cart", you may send it in your `checkAge` dialog.

Comment: @Sushovan, by the way, if you find this answer helpful, could you please mark this answer?

Comment: Still could not figure out the way.